# AngularJS & Protractor - If element was displayed at least once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

How can I test if an element was displayed at least once ?

What I want to do is to set something like a watcher for an element, so when it displays it will trigger some function or assign something to a variable.

And when the page is fully loaded I can test it using `expect()`

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to set `browser.ignoreSynchronization` to `true` in order to avoid waiting for the fully loaded page and for Angular to settle down. In this case, you may add an [explicit wait](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) for an element to become visible:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

var myElm = element(by.id("myid"));
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(myElm), 10000);

expect(myElm.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
expect(myElm.getText()).toEqual("test");
```